# How to send base64 value to rest api using formControlName angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angularjs-directive, base64

I have add-business form in which i need to submit the image as base64. I am trying to convert the image to base64 the value of base64 I am getting in my console. But I want that base64 value in my formControlName so that I can send it to restapi.

add-business.component.html

```
  <form [formGroup]="AddBusinessForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(AddBusinessForm.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" formControlName="comp_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_name.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                  <div *ngIf="buf.comp_name.errors.required">Company Name is required</div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Formation Date</label>
                <div class="input-group masked-input">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control date" formControlName="comp_formation_date" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_formation_date.errors }">
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_formation_date.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="buf.comp_formation_date.errors.required">Formation Date is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>Start Time</label>
                <div class="input-group masked-input">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control time24" formControlName="comp_time_start" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_time_start.errors }">
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_time_start.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="buf.comp_time_start.errors.required">Start Time is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Close Time</label>
                <div class="input-group masked-input">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control time24" formControlName="comp_time_close" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_time_close.errors }">
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_time_close.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="buf.comp_time_close.errors.required">Close Time is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Off Day</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Off Day" formControlName="comp_close_day" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_close_day.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_close_day.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_close_day.errors.required">Off Day is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Description</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Company Description" class="form-control no-resize" formControlName="comp_description" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_description.errors }"></textarea>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_description.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_description.errors.required">Off Day is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="cont_first_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_first_name.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_first_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_first_name.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="cont_last_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_last_name.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_last_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_last_name.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" formControlName="cont_email" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_email.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" formControlName="cont_phone" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_phone.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_phone.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_phone.errors.required">Phone is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Website</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website" formControlName="cont_website" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_website.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_website.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_website.errors.required">Website is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Designation</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Designation" formControlName="cont_designation" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_designation.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_designation.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_designation.errors.required">Designation is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Department</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" formControlName="cont_department" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.cont_department.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.cont_department.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.cont_department.errors.required">Department is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Country</label>
                <select formControlName="comp_country" class="form-control show-tick ms select2" data-placeholder="Select" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_country.errors }">
                    <option>India</option>
                    <option>US</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_country.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_country.errors.required">Country is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select State</label>
                <select formControlName="comp_state" class="form-control show-tick ms select2" data-placeholder="Select" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_state.errors }">
                    <option>Maharashtra</option>
                    <option>Kerala</option>
                    <option>Bihar</option>
                    <option>Uttar Pradesh</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_state.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_state.errors.required">State is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select City</label>
                <select formControlName="comp_city" class="form-control show-tick ms select2" data-placeholder="Select" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_city.errors }">
                    <option>Mumbai</option>
                    <option>Delhi</option>
                    <option>Kolkatta</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_city.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_city.errors.required">City is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>PO Box</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PO Box" formControlName="comp_postal" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_postal.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_postal.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_postal.errors.required">PO Box is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Address</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Company Address" class="form-control no-resize" formControlName="comp_address" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_address.errors }"></textarea>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_address.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_address.errors.required">Company Address is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Latitude</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Latitude" formControlName="comp_lat" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_lat.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_lat.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_lat.errors.required">Latitude is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Longitude</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Longitude" formControlName="comp_long" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_long.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_long.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_long.errors.required">Longitude is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Company Classifications</p>
                <select multiple formControlName="comp_cat" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_cat.errors }">
                    <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_cat.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_cat.errors.required">Company Classifications is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-container">
                <input type="file" id="comp_logo" name="comp_logo" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" formControlName="comp_logo"> 
              </div>
              <div class="card-container">
                <img src="{{comp_logo}}" alt="Selected Image" height="200" width="200">
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Package</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="comp_package" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && buf.comp_package.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && buf.comp_package.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="buf.comp_package.errors.required">Company package is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" (click)="onReset()">Cancel</button>
        </form>
```

add-business.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../../../auth/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-business',
  templateUrl: './add-business.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-business.component.css']
})
export class AddBusinessComponent implements OnInit {
  
  AddBusinessForm: FormGroup;
  ProductForm: FormGroup;
  BroucherForm: FormGroup;
  advertisementForm: FormGroup;
  error: [];
  addbusinessdata = [];

  userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))

  submitted = false;
  
  comp_logo:string | ArrayBuffer=null;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient,public authService: AuthService,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router:Router) { }


  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    let me = this;
    let file = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log(reader.result);
      me.comp_logo=reader.result;
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
 }

  
  ngOnInit(){


this.AddBusinessForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  comp_name: ['', Validators.required],
  comp_formation_date: ['', Validators.required],
  comp_time_start: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_time_close: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_close_day: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_description: ['',Validators.required],
  cont_first_name: ['', Validators.required],
  cont_last_name: ['', Validators.required],
  cont_email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  cont_phone: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]],
  cont_website: ['',Validators.required],
  cont_designation: ['',Validators.required],
  cont_department: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_country: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_state: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_city: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_postal: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_address: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_lat: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_long: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_cat: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_logo: ['',Validators.required],
  comp_package: ['',Validators.required],
});

this.ProductForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  productName: ['',Validators.required],
  productDescription: ['',Validators.required],
  productPrice: ['',Validators.required],
});

this.BroucherForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  companyBroucher: ['',Validators.required],
});

this.advertisementForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  companyImages: ['',Validators.required],
});
  }



get buf() { return this.AddBusinessForm.controls; }

  get pf() { return this.ProductForm.controls; }

  get brf() { return this.BroucherForm.controls; }

  get adf() { return this.advertisementForm.controls; }

 onSubmit(values: any):void {
console.log(values);

if(this.comp_logo==null){
  alert("Please select file");
}else{     
  var fileUplodVM: FileUplodVM={
    comp_logo:this.comp_logo.toString()
}

  this.authService.addNewBusiness(fileUplodVM).subscribe((res: any) =>{ 
    if(res){
      alert("Successfully uploded file");
    }else{
      alert("File upload failed");
    }
    
  },
  error => {
    alert(error.message);
  });
}

this.authService.addNewBusiness(values).subscribe((res:any) => {
  console.log(res);
  this.addbusinessdata = res.data;
  },
  error => this.error = error
 );

this.submitted = true;  

}

onProductSubmit(){
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.ProductForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.ProductForm.value, null, 4));
}

OnBroucherSubmit(){
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.BroucherForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.BroucherForm.value, null, 4));
}

onAdvertisementSubmit(){
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.advertisementForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.advertisementForm.value, null, 4));
}

  onReset() {
  this.submitted = false;
  this.AddBusinessForm.reset();
  }

}


export class FileUplodVM{
  comp_logo: string;
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
addNewBusiness(params) {
return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl+'/company',params)
.pipe(
  map((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  }));
 }
```

Thanks for helping.